# Powermail ext doesn't include css files needed for date picker

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

TYPO3 7.6.15
Powermail 3.18.0

The date picker field does not open the popup calendar. I have narrowed down the cause being because the necessary CSS files are not being included for this feature. Is there an error in my setup? How do I have them included automatically?

This is what I have in my TS Setup:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
  view {
    templateRootPaths >
    templateRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.templateRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/template/mysite/powermail/Templates/
    }
    partialRootPaths >
    partialRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.partialRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/template/mysite/powermail/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths >
    layoutRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.layoutRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/template/mysite/powermail/Layouts/
    }
  }
  _LOCAL_LANG.default {
    datepicker_format_date = d/m/Y
    datepicker_format_time = H:i
    datepicker_format_datetime = d/m/Y H:i
  }
}
```

The only way I have found to make it work correctly is by manually adding it like this:

```
page.includeCSS {
  file4 = EXT:powermail/Resources/Public/Css/Basic.css
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Documentation ist a hint:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/Installation/Index.html#addbootstrapclassesandcsstopowermail

you should

> add the static template Add classes and CSS based on bootstrap (powermail)

There the css is included

Answer (score 0):

Adding the static template file would result in a TypoScript like

> plugin.tx_powermail.settings.BasicCss
>   =EXT:powermail/Resources/Public/Css/Basic.css

this should load everything.
The datepicker styles are originally located in https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Resources/Private/Sass/_DatePicker.scss

Comment: I have tried `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.BasicCss = EXT:powermail/Resources/Public/Css/Basic.css` but it did not include the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell powermail to load the JavaScript libraries by setting a constant in your TypoScript template:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.javascript.addAdditionalJavaScript = 1
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Faq/Index.html#datetimepickernotworking for more information.